# App Engine: Can pull queue tasks handle arbitrary tags?

Tags: google-app-engine

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-pull

Is there a limit on taskqueue pull task tag names, or can there be millions of arbitrary task tags?

Comment: I also didn't notice any issues with mass usage of pull queue tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no documented hard limit, and I wouldn't expect it to be; a couple reasons come to mind:

- Internally tasks are stored in bigtable as everything else, and thus one could imagine tags are indexed as we're used to for our own data, and there's no limit there.

  The database is designed to find indexed data very efficiently, and they purposely denied us of methods to group tags so we couldn't use them to fan-in data, meaning no need to merge-join and thus guaranteed performance that scales indefinitively :)
- [In this thread](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/google-appengine/13aqztz1pb/how-stable-is-pull-queue-task-tagging-for-arbitrary-tags) people are talking about how reliable is the queue when testing the limits, and this quote is interesting:

  > We were using many different tags (basically regrouping events per user
  >   with several million users).

  So at least this one guy just went with it and used millions of tags, with no issues directly related to the practice.